# Asynchronous function node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to understand how to work with asynchronous function in node js. I am a beginner and would like to have some guidance about this error that I am facing. I am doing POST request from my function and pushing the data in an array. The idea is to send the array once the loop counter is done. However, for some reason, i end up receiving the empty array before the execution of the post request. How do i fix this error ?

```
    function checkforcurrency(vals,basecurrency,targetcurrency) {

        var cval = []

        var currencyexchange = basecurrency + "_" + targetcurrency;


        return new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {

                for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {

                    split_string = vals[i].split(/(\d+)/)
                    var currency_determine = split_string[0]
                    var currency_value = parseFloat(split_string[1])
                    console.log('currency', currency_determine)
                    var cexchange = basecurrency + "_" + targetcurrency;


                    if (currency_determine.length < 2) {


                        request.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=' + cexchange + '&compact=y', function (err, res, body) {

                            var s = JSON.parse(body)
                            console.log('sss', s)
                            console.log('cjdjdkkdkd', s[cexchange])

                            baseconversionrate = parseFloat(s[cexchange].val);
                            console.log('cvb', baseconversionrate)

                            var finalres = currency_value * baseconversionrate;
                            console.log('kkk', finalres)
                            if (finalres != null) {
                                console.log('hdhdhhdhdhdhdhdhhd', finalres)
                                cval.push(finalres);

                            }


                        })


                    }
                    if (currency_determine.length > 2) {

                        var currencyexchange = currency_determine + "_" + targetcurrency;
                        request.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=' + currencyexchange + '&compact=y', function (err, res, body) {

                            var s = JSON.parse(body)
                            console.log('sss', s)
                            console.log('ckkdkd', s[currencyexchange])

                            conversionrate = parseFloat(s[currencyexchange].val);
                            var finalres = vals[i] * conversionrate;


                            cval.push(finalres);


                        });


                    }


                }

                setTimeout(resolve, 120000)


                console.log('cva;', cval)
                resolve(cval)


            })


    }


app.post('/financialtrading', function(req, res) {

    console.log('Called',req.body)

    var rev =req.body.revenue;

    var profit = req.body.profit;
    var grossincome = req.body.grossincome;

    var basecurrency = req.body.basecurrency;

    var targetcurrency = req.body.targetcurrency;




       checkforcurrency(rev,basecurrency,targetcurrency).then(function (result) {

           var resu = {"res":result}
           res.send(resu)

        });











});
```

Comment: Take a look at the async/await keywords: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Clean up your code. Fix your indentation. Remove all those completely pointless `console.log()` statements and remove all blank lines. Put your code into http://jshint.com/ and remove all the errors you see. If you don't understand an error, read about it. After your code is clean, remove the duplication. You have the same piece of code copy-pasted two times, make a function out of that. *After that*, read about the `request-promise` package and `Promise.all()`.